# Create splash screen in the same Activity

Tags: android

I need to show splash layout file until operation is completed and than change to main layout. 
Here is an example .

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    //Here app is copying files or something other it doesn't mater.
        RelativeLayout panel = new RelativeLayout(this);
    //Here is creating of main layout 

        setContentView(panel);
```

I need to show splash screen while operations are performing (between two methods setContentView) And than I need to set main layout, 
I have tried to do in this way but it shows only black screen and only than shows main layout (panel). 
Where is the problem ? 
Thx for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, if you're not doing heavy stuff precisely on  `setContentView(R.layout.main)`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    handler = new Handler();

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Do some heavy stuff
            return null;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                 @Override
                 public void run(){
                     setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 }
            });
        }
   }.execute();
}
```

**EDIT**   You can check this [True SplashScreen](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample taken from my project:

Layout page, you can customize the progress bar as you want:

`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/inquiry_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_progress"></ProgressBar>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/panel_inquiry"
>
   .....

</FrameLayout>
```

`

Java source code:

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FrameLayout inquiryFrame;

inquiryFrame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.panel_inquiry);
progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.inquiry_progress);

In order to show the splash screen/do work in background

private void callService() {

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    inquiryFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    new ServerReqAsync().execute(this
            , ServiceConstants.getRequestList());

}
```

When background job completed, just view the activity default layout
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
inquiryFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Thanks